# How to trigger a github action build from the pull request page?

Tags: android, kotlin, github, github-actions, pull-request

I have configured a github actions build for pull requests. Sometimes the build fails because of a time out when trying to solve some dependencies from a self hosted repository. So far what I have to do to run the build again is to make a commit (i.e. add space somewhere in the code) but I dont want to have to do that all the time.

How can I can configure a button in the page of the github pull request to run the build again?

Below my pull request triggers:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'master'
```

Comment: Would it be an option to trigger the pipeline through a comment on the PR? You could eventually call the Github api from somewhere else as well (command line or Rest Client).

Answer (score 0):

```
uses: nick-fields/retry@v2
with:
  timeout_minutes: 10
  max_attempts: 3
```

you can try ti add this it will add timeout and retry attemptes